# How to encrypt SQLite DB in an electron app?

Tags: sqlite, electron, sqlcipher

I have an electron app which persists data in an SQLite db stored in my machine. I have all the setup for the CRUD operation and the application works fine. Now I need to encrypt the SQLite DB file. I searched online for solution but all the solution are for pre-encrypted DB which is being decrypted inside Electron.

The requirement is, user will provide the password using which the app will encrypt the DB file and going forward user will provide the password to decrypt and perform the CRUD operation

Any idea how to achieve this?

**P.S.:** I have checked with SQLCipher docs and I don't find what I needed. So far, I am using **sqlite3** node module to perform CRUD

**Edit 1**: I tried to use [sqlite-cipher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-cipher) module and I was able to encrypt the db in a separate js file. but when I integrate the same with the electron ipcMain, the app closes due to high RAM consumption.
Any suggestions???

Comment: I know this is old but I'm facing a similar usecase and I want to use the password passed by the user as the key to encrypt the database. How did you achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQLite the best option is use SQLCipher. The problem is that you will have to compile new binaries to work and there are some limitations with the versions of SQLite and SQLcipher for node.

You can use this package: https://github.com/journeyapps/node-sqlcipher

or compiling manually, here you have an example https://gist.github.com/aguynamedben/14253e34bc7e0a881d99c8e45eb45a47

Comment: As of now, `journeyapps/node-sqlcipher` is a very very bad recommendation. It's unmaintained for over 2 years and broken on Macs with the Apple Silicon Chip.